# How to fetch only featured title articles using custom code inside current template index.php file in joomla 3.5?

Tags: joomla3.0

Can anyone let me know how can I get all featured articles in current template index.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Articles aren't sorted based off of templates, but rather the category they are associated with. If you are intent on it, a MySQL call written in PHP can search for and load all articles that meet your requirements and can then be displayed with a loop through the objects/arrays. Note: There are native Joomla modules and menu items that can achieve the same results without resorting to custom code.